# Is there a way to use .find() on elements after being added with jquery

Tags: jquery

The application I've build adds multiple elements according to the data it gets from the database.

With the help of jQuery I'm adding more elements to this page.

Alle of these elements can be saved on their own but there is also one button that can save them all by triggering the 'click' event of all these save links.

The code for the button works just fine when being fired after the page has loaded however when one or more new elements have been added the button only fires the 'click' event of the links that were present on page load.

**HMTL example**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element" id="row-1"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>
    <div class="element" id="row-2"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>
    <div class="element" id="row-4"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>
    <div class="element" id="row-5"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="saveAllRows" data-container="#container" data-target="a.save">save all</a>
<a href="#" id="addRow" data-container="#container">add row</a>
```

**jQuery example**

```
$(document).on('click','#saveAllRows',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $(link.data('container')).find(link.data('target')).trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('click','#addRow',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    //Normaly the content which is appended comes from an ajax request
    //I've checked the returned value and it looks just the way it should.
    //All the rows get their unique ID from the backend 
    $(link.data('container')).append('<div class="element" id="row-6"><a href="#" class="save">save</a></div>');
});

$(document).on('click','.save',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    console.log(link.closest('div.element').attr('id'));
});
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jas6ymr5/) where you can see that it works just fine when the new content is being loaded without ajax call, however it does not work when you start using ajax loaded content.

I'm unable to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: **Your code should work**; whether the data originates from AJAX, or a static string (like in you example). Can you show your AJAX request, and how you're injecting that response into the page?

Comment: Sure, give me a few min. I'll put the code in a fiddle.

Comment: e.g, https://jsfiddle.net/jas6ymr5/1/ uses AJAX, and still works (and https://jsfiddle.net/jas6ymr5/2/ with simulated unique IDs)

Comment: Argh god, I feel so stupid... i didn't bind the click event on the individual links the right way. Guess it helps just sharing your problem. Thanks for the help and time @Matt